# Suggetions on Opencart robots.txt

Tags: opencart, robots.txt, opencart-3

I'm a bit confused about how my robots.txt file should be. My website is [www.partspatibd.com](https://www.partspatibd.com)

Can anyone check my current file? See if it's OK or not...

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /*&filter
Disallow: /*&limit
Disallow: /*&sort
Disallow: /*?route=account/
Disallow: /*?route=affiliate/
Disallow: /*?route=checkout/
Allow: /

sitemap: https://partspatibd.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Are you encountering a particular problem with your current file?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience in OpenCart 2 and 3 I suggest you to use following configuration for **robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*route=account/
Disallow: /*route=affiliate/
Disallow: /*route=checkout/
Disallow: /*route=product/search
Disallow: /index.php?route=product/product*&manufacturer_id=
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /catalog
Disallow: /download
Disallow: /system
Disallow: /*?sort=
Disallow: /*&sort=
Disallow: /*?order=
Disallow: /*&order=
Disallow: /*?limit=
Disallow: /*&limit=
Disallow: /*?filter=
Disallow: /*&filter=
Disallow: /*?filter_name=
Disallow: /*&filter_name=
Disallow: /*?filter_sub_category=
Disallow: /*&filter_sub_category=
Disallow: /*?filter_description=
Disallow: /*&filter_description=
Disallow: /*?tracking=
Disallow: /*&tracking=

Sitemap: https://partspatibd.com/sitemap.xml

Host: https://partspatibd.com/
```

This will protect system directories and queries from unnecessary indexation. Your **Sitemap** file is approachable and totally fine. **Host** statement is recommended.